# a single word or short desciption of a person projecting delusional selflessness after hurting someone

Tags: word-choice, psychology

What would be a good way to describe a person who is projecting delusional selflessness ?

Example would be: Person "A" hurts you. When you try to take revenge they say they are the ones who have the higher moral ground because they wont be "fighting back" and they are not doing so because they are selfless and their love and concern for you is stopping them from "fighting back". If they were selfless and had their love and concern as a priority they should not have "done something not so right" ( I am not interested in debating this scenario, just want a short description for future reference that is all)

Is Delusional passive aggressive righteousness a good choice ?

Comment: Wait, are we talking about someone's parents? That could change things.

Comment: Why would parents change things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for "*delusional passive-aggressive righteousness*"; "***self-righteous***" or "***sanctimonious***" will do.

M-W:

> ***self-righteous***: *having or characterized by a certainty, especially an unfounded one, that one is totally correct or morally superior.*

and

> ***sanctimonious***: *making a hypocritical show of righteousness, piety, etc.*

Note that as this sentiment is as old as humanity, there are [any number of synonyms available to you](http://thesaurus.com/browse/self-righteous).

Answer (score 1):

Dan Bron is spot on.  I like self-righteous and sanctimonious in this situation, because they are a bit more descriptive.  Personally, I like to keep it short and sweet and use the word pious.  It's not the main definition, but it is very applicable.

M-W:

> ***pi·ous*** - adjective \ˈpī-əs\
>
> > :  *deeply religious : devoted to a particular religion*
> > :  ***falsely appearing to be good or moral***

Answer (score 0):

How about hypocritical? morally backward? self-unaware? inconsistent?

Answer (score 0):

First, **everyone feels hurt by others**.  It's part of human nature.  And the closer others are to us, the higher the standards we typically set, so that it becomes very easy for others that are close to us to hurt us because we set such high standards and expectations for them that, really, no human is going to meet all the time.

> "Oft expectation fails, and most oft there  Where most it promises...
> All's Well That Ends Well (II, i, 145-146)
>
> "It sometimes seems to me that all the disappointment, hurt, and anger
> in the world comes from someone not meeting expectations, either
> someone else’s or their own. The problem is not that people let you
> down or that you don’t accomplish all that you ought to accomplish.
> The problem is that you keep wishing for what you think should be
> instead of accepting what is." [and quite a bit more on-point
> discussion at this link from the book *Doing the Right
> Thing*](http://www.mariannepowers.com/expect.htm)

So as in your example, Person A is going to hurt you and the higher you set your expectations for that person the more often you will feel hurt and angry by Person A - that's just human nature.

> "What happens when our expectations, conscious or not, are
> unfulfilled? This is the source of the disappointment that
> expectations are famous for. What we do with that disappointment
> determines how much pleasure we can have in the ensuing moments. If I
> created my expectation as a kind of unspoken pact with another person
> or the universe then I'm likely to feel cheated, angry and/or hurt.
> Things didn't work out the way I thought they would, so someone is to
> blame. What's important here is not to find out why things didn't go
> the way they 'should' have and who is responsible for that. The real
> question is who decided that things should go a certain way and that
> any other way was unacceptable. And I think we all know the answer to
> that one.
>
> *Expecting the world to treat you fairly because you are a good
> person is a little like expecting a bull not to attack you because you
> are a vegetarian. - Dennis Wholey*" [and quite a bit more useful
> information is in this essay *Reflections on
> Expectations*](http://www.huna.org/html/reflexpectations.html)

This is how almost all human conflict starts.  Person A doesn't meet the expectations of Person B so Person B becomes hurt and angry, and feels the need to "take revenge" as is so accurately stated in the question.

The taking of revenge by Person B will, in turn, almost certainly hurt Person A, who will then feel the need to "take revenge" on Person B, perpetuating and escalating the cycle as the revenge usually becomes more and more hurtful as each person seeks to do a bit worse to the other.

However, it is possible that at any point in this cycle either Person A or Person B will recognize that a cycle of progressively more hurtful revenge has started and that person will seek to stop the cycle by refusing to "fight back" as described in the question.

There's a very good word to describe the behavior of someone who may have initially been accused of causing some hurt or even have participated in some cycles of progressively worse taking of revenge, but recognizes the unhealthy cycle and decides to refuse to participate in it any more.  It's called being an *adult*

> "When I was a child, I spake as a child, I understood as a child, I
> thought as a child: but when I became a man, I put away childish
> things."  1 Cor 13:11 KJV

On the other hand, while Person A in your example above is being an *adult*, Person B is "playing the blame game".

> "**Playing the Blame Game:** Some people handle conflict by
> criticizing and blaming the other person for the situation. They see
> admitting any weakness on their own part as a weakening of their
> credibility, and avoid it at all costs, and even try to shame them for
> being 'at fault.'" [Conflict Resolution Mistakes To
> Avoid](http://stress.about.com/od/relationships/tp/conflictres.htm)

Comment: No this person has definitely hurt me, with more or less malicious intent.

Comment: @qwrty well perhaps Person A was in a revenge cycle with you where they were taking revenge for something you did.  But regardless of how it started, if Person A now recognizes that there is no point in continuing the revenge cycle and refuses to "fight back" furhter as you state, then Person A has begun to act like an adult.